# How to highlight the word by word while playing audio in HTML?

Tags: html

How to highlight the words while the audio playing in html, like a karaoke machine?

Is it possible in HTML?

If yes, please provide suggestions/procedures to proceed...

Comment: You would like to highlight words as they are said/sang in the audio playing?

Comment: you mean like a karaoke machine????

Comment: first of all.. yes it is possible.. but in jQuery /javascript.... not in HTML

Comment: Thanks... But, how to proceed it by using Javascript/Jquery? Can you please give the solution? What are the procedures to handle while the audio reading? For an examle I have a swf file, which contains some sentences and the flash object is embedded in html. I can place the audio icons over there. By clicking the icon the audio will start to play. While reading the respective words should be highlight...

Comment: @Madhan check out my, just edited, answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/DnV4z/  really simple way this could be done.. of course this is not a solution

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible in HTML.

You can probably use JavaScript / jQuery to highlight each word manually, but you would need to program the timer yourself. A browser can't listen to songs and recognize words.

Comment: Thanks... But, how to proceed it by using Javascript/Jquery? Can you please give the solution? What are the procedures to handle while the audio reading? For an examle I have a swf file, which contains some sentences and the flash object is embedded in html. I can place the audio icons over there. By clicking the icon the audio will start to play. While reading the respective words should be highlight...

Comment: You didn't mention anything about Flash, that is completely different and can't easily be controlled by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible (if you consider javascript to be a part of HTML, which many people do).

Though this will require a lot of work to be fully functional functional.

---

If you have a speech-2-text algorithm you should generate a mapping between at what time what word is being said. By so you can use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to make the word highlighted when enough time has passed, using a function that checks what words to be replaced every `N.f` seconds, using `setInterval` or such.

If you don't have a speech-2-text algorithm you'll need to manually create the mapping mentioned, which is tedious.

---

A browser cannot, by default, parse out what is being said in an audiofile.

Though theoretically you could have the browser do this, but then you will have to use an external resource such as flash/java to implement a text-2-speech algorithm client side, and as said; a lot of work.

---

### But I meant HTML5!?

This might be possible in the future using HTML5, there is/was a proposed Speech API which you can read more about under the following link:

- [w3.org - Speech Input API Specification](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html)
- [HTML5 Speech API - mozillawiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/HTML5_Speech_API#1.Speech_Input_API)